# Multi-block query on Redshift from Excel via ODBC

Tags: excel, odbc, amazon-redshift

With MS SQL Server, something like the following would work fine when importing data via ODBC from MS SQL Server.

```
SET NOCOUNT ON;

SELECT * 
INTO #temp_table
FROM my_table;

SELECT *
FROM #temp_table;
```

However, this does not work via ODBC from AWS Redshift, it only seems to support a single query block, does not even recognize the SET NOCOUNT ON part.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

Amazon Redshift is based on PostgreSQL 8.0.2.

`SET NOCOUNT ON` appears to be specific to Microsoft SQL Server, so it will not function in Amazon Redshift.

Also the `#temp_table` syntax is not standard. For PostgreSQL and Redshift, it would probably be:

```
SELECT *
INTO TEMP temp_table
FROM my_table;

SELECT *
FROM temp_table;
```

Comment: Would you mind testing your suggestion above and letting us know the outcome? I tested it on my end and it doesn't work.

Comment: I'm not familiar with using Excel to access databases via ODBC. You could try running the SQL code on Redshift itself to check the syntax, and then run it from Excel. If the Redshift runs the query but Excel doesn't, then the issue is with the connectivity method.